# Cancelling onSubmit with JS Field Validation

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to validate length of password and display a warning message but message is temporary.
I have tried using the onsubmit attribute with the submit button but it still doesn't work.

```js
        function validate()
        {
            var pw = document.getElementById("password").value
            if(pw.length<8)
            {
                document.getElementById("span").innerHTML = "Password length must be more than 7 characters.<br/>"
            }
        }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="">
            <input type="text" id="password"/>
            <br/>
            <span id="span" style="color:red;"></span>
            <button onclick="validate()">Submit</button>
        </form>
        
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: The text will be changed only when the code that changes it runs. What do you want to happen instead?

Comment: Try add this attribute in button tag ---  type="button" --- or try move <script> tag in head section

Comment: After adding the type="button" in button tag the text is there permanently, could you explain why this works?

Comment: A button inside a form is type `submit` by default. You can prevent form submission by setting it to `button`.

Comment: Are you asking how to prevent form submission?

Comment: Let me know if my answer helped below, don't forget to choose the answer that helped the most, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There were a few things fixed below:

- Pass the event to your `validate()`, like this: `onclick="validate(event)"`.
- Cancel the regular event that happens with onsubmit by means of [**`Event.preventDefault()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) and `return false`, but the former is much more important.

Notice what you see below when password is too short and when password is long enough:

```js
        function validate(ev)
        {
            var pw = document.getElementById("password").value
            if(pw.length<8)
            {
                document.getElementById("span").innerHTML = "Password length must be more than 7 characters.<br/>";
                ev.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="">
            <input type="text" id="password"/>
            <br/>
            <span id="span" style="color:red;"></span>
            <button onclick="validate(event)">Submit</button>
        </form>
        
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
      document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', validate);

        function validate(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            const form = new FormData(event.target);
            const password = form.get('password').trim();

            if (password.length < 8) {
                document.getElementById("span").innerHTML = "Password length must be more than 7 characters.<br/>"
                return;
            }

            event.target.submit();
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="">
        <input name="password" type="text" id="password"/>
        <br/>
        <span id="span" style="color:red;"></span>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Your script should look something like this:

```
       document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', validate);

        function validate(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            const form = new FormData(event.target);
            const password = form.get('password').trim();

            if (password.length < 8) {
                document.getElementById("span").innerHTML = "Password length must be more than 7 characters.<br/>"
                return;
            }

            event.target.submit();
        }
```

I put the .trim() because it is usually a good idea to trim the inputs.
Consider this if you are using the inline attributes:
"You can find HTML attribute equivalents for many of the event handler properties; however, you shouldn't use these — they are considered bad practice. It might seem easy to use an event handler attribute if you are doing something really quick, but they quickly become unmanageable and inefficient. " This is from the mdn documentation -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events

Comment: Your function **always** runs `event.preventDefault();`.  Isn't that incorrect?  Shouldn't it be after the `if(){...}`?  Take a look at my answer: I run `event.preventDefault()` in the right place, after the if, and I have a snippet that works to prove it.

Comment: Personally I do that, because I handle everything else after the checks. I am not sure if his validate() function is only those few lines of code. And I agree that it would be more correct if it is after the if() statement if the OP doesn't handle the event after the password check. Either way it would depend on the code. Considering that it could be a login form or a registration form my suggestion would be to prevent the default behavior and handle the form after that.

Comment: Can you please make a code snippet like in the OP's post to demonstrate your code?

Comment: I edited the post with the working snippet.

Comment: I don't see a snippet?  You need to use the `<>` button in the edit-question editor.  Notice how the OP's question has a "run code snippet" button.  If you use the `<>` button, you'll get a code snippet too.

Comment: Thank you for showing me, now it should be visible.

Comment: No problem, you added a `return` to the `if`, and it now works.  Nice.  Thanks for adding, that makes it clear that it does work.

Answer (score 0):

```js
            var ssn = document.getElementById("ssn");
    var current = document.getElementById("current");
    
    ssn.oninput = function(event) {
      current.textContent = ssn.value;
    }
```

```html
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <title>Document</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form action="">
                <label for="ssn">password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="ssn" inputmode="numeric" minlength="9" maxlength="12"
            pattern="(?!000)([0-6]\d{2}|7([0-6]\d|7[012]))([ -])?(?!00)\d\d\3(?!0000)\d{4}"
            required autocomplete="off">
        <br>
        <label for="ssn">Value:</label>
        <span id="current"></span>
                <span id="span" style="color:red;"></span>
                <button onclick="validate()">Submit</button>
            </form>
            
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Your answer should include some explanation. Please see [answer].

Answer (score -1):

You could use the `submit` event on the form and return a status (`boolean`) on whether or not to let the request go through. (This is what is usually used for form validation.)

```html
<form action="" onsubmit="return validate()">
```

```js
function validate()
{
    var pw = document.getElementById("password").value
    if(pw.length<8)
    {
        document.getElementById("span").innerHTML = "Password length must be more than 7 characters.<br/>";
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

---

If the function returns `true`, it means the form is valid and the submission will go through.

If it returns `false`, it will show the error message and will not submit the form.

Comment: You deleted my edit where all I did was make your code into a code snippet.  Is there any reason you don't want to use a code snippet with your code?  If your code works, then great, let's see it on display, right?

Comment: @HoldOffHunger you edited in a code snippet with different code from what i posted, also a code snippet isn't necessary here as my intention was to highlight only the parts that need changing